# Source for split between דיני ממונות and דיני נפשות

Tags: sources-mekorot, capital-punishment, beit-din-court, lomdus

There's a fairly commonly quoted idea in נזיקין masechtos, that a difference exists between דיני ממונות (monetary cases) and דיני נפשות (capital cases); that by דיני ממונות the חייב [whoever is חייב] is חייב from the outset, and the purpose of the דין is just to be מבאר (to clarify) who is חייב, but they don't actually do anything; in contradistinction to דיני נפשות, where the decision of בית דין actually creates the דין.
Proofs to this are, traditionally, the rule that a person could be obligated to pay money, even without a בית דין; but one who kills someone who is clearly חייב מיתה before the פסק בית דין is himself חייב מיתה, while one who does so *after* the פסק is not killed ("גברא קטילא קטל").
קנסות are generally put together with דיני נפשות, based on a ירושלמי (*source?*) that rules that without a פסק בית דין one would not be obligated to pay קנסות, even on the level of לצאת ידי שמים.

My problem is that I have all this wonderful תורה, and no source. So my question is, **who among the ראשונים and / or אחרונים discussed this idea?**
*Names and marei mekomos, please.*

Comment: On which Masechta Sanhedrin or Makkos

Comment: @sam why does it have to be on a specific masechta, or one of those two? See R. Elchanan Kovetz Shiurim 2:14, and there's a Steipler on this in Kehilos Yaakov on Bava Kamma (I'm pretty sure; those are both from memory)

Comment: @Matt That's the kind of stuff I'm looking for....I'll look into it, thanks :)

Comment: @sam Either, both -- as long as it's a name that I can put into my notes.

Comment: @Shokhet I have a lot to say on this sugya actually; I don't think that your Teyreh is so glatt even though I've heard/seen it in multiple places. Some more: there are important rishonim to be seen on Makkos (around daf 5 for knas, daf 11b for nefashos), a rosh that I think is in the first ch of bava kamma, a minchas chinuch, and a Ketzos (somewhere in the first four simanim of C.M.). Also check the nosei keilim on the rambam Melachim perek 9 or so. If you're actually going through the sugya that's where to look

Comment: Sanhedrin 32 is a good place to start